# HTML img is not loading on browser

Tags: html, google-chrome, browser

I'm learning web development.

My problem is that the image is not showing up in my browser. The code is

```
<img src="images/IMG_0489.png" alt="Anne Capongcol profile picture">
```

The image is in the images folder and the filename is exactly like this (IMG_0489.png).

I've tried removing the image folder and just place the image file with the html but it's still not loading on my browser.

I've also tried changing the image but it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the image file is located in the `images` folder in the same folder as the current page:

```
<img src="./images/IMG_0489.png" alt="Anne Capongcol profile picture">
```

If the image file is located in the same folder as the current page:

```
<img src="./IMG_0489.png" alt="Anne Capongcol profile picture">
```

If the image file is located in the `images` folder in the folder one level up from the current folder:

```
<img src="../images/IMG_0489.png" alt="Anne Capongcol profile picture">
```

If the image file is located in the folder one level up from the current folder:

```
<img src="../IMG_0489.png" alt="Anne Capongcol profile picture">
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this detailed guide. I'll definitely refer to it in the future. :-)

Comment: You’re welcome @Anne13, can you just make my answer as _accepted_ so that everyone can benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

without the folder `folder_name`

```
<img src="./image_name" alt="Alt Tag">
```

With the folder `folder`:

```
<img src="./folder_name/image_name" alt="Alt tag">
```